# Conditionally choose a value on the left hand side of an assignment statement?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to conditionally choose a value on the **left** hand side of an assignment statement (in C#)?

If I was assigning one of two values to a *single* variable, I could do this:

```
var1 = (mode == "A" ? 
          someList.Any(itm => itm.prop == value) : 
          someList.Any(itm => itm.prop == value2)  );

or 

var1 = someList.Any(itm => itm.prop == (mode == "A" ? value : value2));
```

But suppose I want to populate one of two variables with a value:

```
if (mode == "A")
    var1 = someList.Any(itm => itm.prop == value);

if (mode == "B")
    var2 = someList.Any(itm => itm.prop == value);
```

Is there any way to do this in one line? (non working) example:

```
(mode == "A" ? var1 : var2) = someList.Any(itm => itm.prop == value);
```

[I know I can introduce a variable and assign it to var1 or var2 before getting from somelist

```
var temp = (mode == "A" ? var1 : var2);
temp = someList.Any(itm => itm.prop == value);
```

]

**UPDATE**
@HimBromBeere - I know that there are restrictions on the target of an assignment, and I don't *need* to do this, I just wondered if it was possible, in the same way that usage of the conditional operator is possible.

The code snippets were meant to illustrate and further explain the question.

...But I succeeded in getting two wonderful, useful nuggets of information from @EricLippert and @Servy: The *ConditionalAssignment* / *SelectVariable* function and the C# *ref* function.

I'll probably never use them (Eric - I'll stick to IF), but it helps me to grow.

Thanks everyone for all the useful feedback.

Comment: Using an indexer, for example with a dictionary: `dict[(expression)] = bar`, or using reflection. Explain your use case.

Comment: No, only variables can be the target of an assignment. However you can not target a variable variable-name.

Comment: Why yo even need this? Even if you *could* you´d have to check wheather `var1` or `var2` is set to anything, making you checki the same condition twice.

Comment: Your solution on the last line won´t work either, as `temp` will simply be overridden by the return-value of any (which is a boolean). However this won´t be relfected in neither `var1` nor `var2`.

Comment: To make the solution on the last line work you would need to make temp a ref local, which is a new feature in C# 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a helper method, but please do not.  Just write the code like normal C# code; if you want a conditional assignment then write a conditional assignment with an `if`.

The helper method would be:

```
static void ConditionalAssignment<T>(bool b, ref T v1, ref T v2, T value)
{
  if (b) v1 = value else v2 = value;
}
```

And then at the call site

```
ConditionalAssignment(condition, ref v1, ref v2, value);
```

In general the way you do something "in one line" is you make a method that does whatever you want and then call it. **Methods are the fundamental technique for abstractions in C#.**

In cases like this where the abstraction is a single statement wrapped up in a method, *it's often better to just put that statement in line*. This is definitely such a case. If you want the behaviour of an `if` then just write an `if` please.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using the `ref local` feature introduced in C# 7.2/7.3. A generic form of

```
if (a)
    b = d;
else
    c = d;
```

can be simplified into

```
(a? ref b : ref c) = d;
```

per [this proposal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.2/conditional-ref). While it's unclear when it's exactly added, on VS 2019 all .NET Framework project will target 7.3 and all .NET Core project will target 7.3/8.0 or later, so this feature should always be available on latest VS. Thus, you can use

```
(mode == "A" ? ref var1 : ref var2) = someList.Any(itm => itm.prop == value);
```

Comment: Note though `ref` cannot be used majority of left sides you can encounter (e.g.  indexeres, properties etc.), more or less it just works for local variables of simpler types.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a variable that is itself a reference to another variable (rather than one that holds a value).  You can also write a method that returns a reference to one of a choice of variables based on some condition.

```
ref bool SelectVariable(ref bool a, ref bool b)
{
    if (mode == "A")
        return ref a;
    else
        return ref b;
}
ref bool referenceToVariable = ref SelectVariable(ref var1, ref var2);
referenceToVariable = someList.Any(itm => itm.prop == value);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        var var1 = "";
        var var2 = "";
        var mode = "A";
        var pointlessVar = "";
        pointlessVar =  mode == "A"  ? var1 = "blah" : var2 = "de blah";
```